# Bs4 creates the object very slow

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have problem. ONLY WITH PYTHON2.

```
r = self.session.get('http://..................')
print "CREATE BS"
print datetime.now()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
print "CREATE BS END"
print datetime.now()
```

The result is:

```
CREATE BS
2017-09-01 11:45:22.822256
CREATE BS END
2017-09-01 11:46:56.992892
```

I don't think that this is normal: 1,5 minutes to parse HTML. 1 week ago I didn't have problem with this source code. Anyone who knows about issues with bs4?

With python3 everything is about 3 seconds.

Comment: What url are you using, this might help work out why this is happening, also what's your internet speed like? :)

Comment: use the `lxml` parser , it is very fast compared to html parser. You need to have lxml installed .

Comment: Doesn't matter of the URL bro or the Internet speed, I make the request before the first print ;) The problem is with the parsing.
The lxml parsing has the same problem .... very slow. I tried

Comment: Guys ... With python3 there is no problem. Only with python2. What the F....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guys I don't believe but the problem was with the encodings :D After a lot of debug in bs4 source code I found the solution. Solution is:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml', from_encoding="utf8")
```

This from_encoding="utf8" makes all the magic. But this is definitely bug in bs4. Should work without this :) As I said python3 doesn't have problems.

Comment: If this answer worked for you, you can accept your own answer.